# What is the time complexity of this subset finder?

Tags: time-complexity, subset

I have solved the question subset question on leetcode [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/)

But i am having a hard time understanding its time complexity since its a backtracking algorithm with copying lists involved.

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums):
        if not nums:
            return []

        results = [[]]

        path = []
        def dfs(i):
            for i in range(i, len(nums)):
                path.append(nums[i])
                results.append(path[:])
                dfs(i + 1)
                path.remove(nums[i])

        dfs(0)
        return results
```

Notice the list is being copied with

```
path[:]
```

Can anyone give a clear time-complexity analysis of this code, please?

Comment: What do you **think** the time complexity is, and why?

Comment: I can not reasonabliy think of something